# play a particular file from playlist with ExoPlayer 2.8

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm working with Exoplayer 2.8.0, I have simpleList filled with an array of streams audios, it's working fine using the notifications buttons, next, previews and stop, but if want to play a particular song from the list, it's always start with the first song on the list, it's don't matter which song of the list I clicked,  always start on the first one.

This how I made the playlist:

```
// Create the Playlist from Array
    mediaSources = new MediaSource[radioList_2.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < radioList_2.size(); i++) {
        mediaSources[i] = new ExtractorMediaSource( Uri.parse(radioList_2.get(i)),
                dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

    }

    concatenatingMediaSource=new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
    concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(concatenatingMediaSource);
    player.prepare(new ConcatenatingMediaSource(false,mediaSources));
    sTartNotification();
```

This is the code use when I click an item of the list:

```
  MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(strUrl),
            dataSourceFactory,
            extractorsFactory,
            mainHandler,
            null);

//    player.prepare(mediaSource);       
//playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(null);


    concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
    player.prepare(new ConcatenatingMediaSource(true,mediaSource));

    sTartNotification();
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    //concatenatingMediaSource=new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    // concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(0,mediaSource);
```

I have tried the comments lines too, it's start playing but then the navigation buttons stop working, it's like the playlist not longer exits.

I have read this:[How to play a particular video from ExoPlayer playlist android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709105/how-to-play-a-particular-video-from-exoplayer-playlist-android)
but the seek function it's not working for me.

Thanks, 
help will be appreciate

Comment: check this link : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4375

Answer (score 1):

Try to use single MediaSource and pass URL of the audio/video you want to play. If you want to seek, pass the eventTime also.

```
public void preparePlayer(String url, long lastEventTime) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "XYZ"));
    ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    MediaSource mediaSource;
    if (url.endsWith(".m3u8")) {
        mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(url), dataSourceFactory, null, null);
    } else {
        mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(url), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    }

    // Prepare the player with the source.
    simpleExolayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    if (lastEventTime > 0) {
        simpleExolayer.seekTo(lastEventTime * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @zeero, with this code it's playing the one I click which is good, but navigation buttons still don't work, it looks like the play list got destroyed

Comment: You need to handle the navigation buttons yourself like on nextButton Click increment index and get new url and then call preparePlayer method.

Comment: Thank your again, any link where I can read about it?, any code example? That would be great.

Thanks,
Oscar